# android how to call invalidate(Rect)

Tags: android, invalidation

I create class that extends LinerLayout and add many elements on view, also I add circle with
etc canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 10) and when I implement onTouchEvent I am not sure how to redraw only that element(circle). which parameters to set in "Rect" so I can send it to  invalidate(Rect).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the specific example, I think this code example does what you want.  I moved your coordinates into variables (cx, cy, r) just to make it clear.   Based on what you mentioned, I think you would call this from within your LinearLayout subclass.

```
    int cx = 100;
    int cy = 100;
    int r = 10;

    canvas.DrawCircle( cx, cy, r );

    int l = cx - r - 1;
    int t = cy - r - 1;
    int r = cx + r + 1;
    int b = cy + r + 1;

    Rect bounds = new Rect(l, t, r, b);
    invalidate(bounds);
```

I added an extra pixel on all sides just to overlap the circle a bit to ensure the entire area is invalidated.  Based on my experience, it looks like you can include negative values or values that exceed the dimensions of the canvas.

Comment: Ok this is useful thanks a lot, now I have more questions.
1. In that circle I have text witch I create with canvas.drawText so will this redraw and that text.
2. When I create image with canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap, 100, 100, Paint) how to defines how image width and height can I do it in Bitmap Object or I can do it in canvas.drawBitmap
Thanks

Comment: Answers: 1) if you do the invalidate in the containing LinearLayout, the text that falls within the invalidate rectangle will get repainted.  2) There's several versions of canvas.drawBitmap. The version you mentioned uses the width/height of the bitmap object.  If you want Canvas to scale the bitmap to a different size when painting, try using public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint).

Comment: I try first example but it calls "onDraw" and redraw all content from view and just circle witch I marked. Here is my code

centerdField.setColor(Color.rgb(10, 200, 220));
int l = 100 - 10 - 1;
int t = 100 - 10 - 1;
int r = 100 + 10 + 1;
int b = 100 + 10 + 1;

Rect bounds = new Rect(l, t, r, b);
invalidate(bounds);

Here I just change color of the circle and if I use that color on other elements in view they will change to.

Thanks for help.

Comment: The color of the other elements shouldn't change unless you share the Paint object (which contains the color) with other drawing calls to Canvas.

Comment: Yes but is it right way that it calls "onDraw" so all object are redraw and not just object that I change color?

Comment: Yes. Android calls your onDraw() and you redraw all objects.  Only the ones that intersect with the invalidated rectangle actually get rendered.